# Get google calendarID from Google calendar name using API in python

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

How can I retrieve the calendar ID of various calendars on my google calendar by using the API, I am aware that using the

```
page_token = None
while True:
  calendar_list = service.calendarList().list(pageToken=page_token).execute()
  for calendar_list_entry in calendar_list['items']:
    print calendar_list_entry['summary']
  page_token = calendar_list.get('nextPageToken')
  if not page_token:
    break
```

It will  return the name but I would like to get it to return the CalendarId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[google API `calendarList` resource representation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList#resource)

You could just print out the entry itself, instead of a single key.

```
page_token = None
while True:
  calendar_list = service.calendarList().list(pageToken=page_token).execute()
  for calendar_list_entry in calendar_list['items']:
    print calendar_list_entry
  page_token = calendar_list.get('nextPageToken')
  if not page_token:
    break
```

Or directly get the `id`:

```
print calendar_list_entry["id"]
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed